# how to cast ArrayList to ArrayList<MyType>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, arraylist, casting

Im new to .net coming from Java. A line of code I have return an `ArrayList`, but I know that all the elements are of `MyType`. How can I easily cast to a templated `ArrayList`? To reiterate, I have

```
ArrayList arr = getArrayList();
```

and I want

```
ArrayList<MyType> arr = getArrayList();
```

I tried `ArrayList<MyType> arr = getArrayList() as ArrayList<MyType>` but it says `Class 'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not have type parameters`

Comment: Maybe `List<MyType>`?

Comment: `ArrayList` is a holdover from the days before generics. It's probably not what you want.

Comment: @Magus Well Im stuck with getting a non-generic `ArrayList` as my return, so I need to work with it at least a little

Comment: NOTE: an ArrayList is not type safe. Like the answers are pointing out, you really need to go with a type safe `List<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a generic `ArrayList` type in .Net (that's a Java thing). In .Net, you need to use a `List<T>` instead. Additionally, you can't just cast to make the conversion. You need to do this:

```
List<MyType> arr = getArrayList().Cast<MyType>().ToList();
```

And while we're at it, you should check whether you really need a List at all, or whether a plain `IEnumerable<MyType>` might be good enough:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> arr = getArrayList().Cast<MyType>();
```

or

```
var arr = getArrayList().Cast<MyType>();
```

Comment: Visual Studios says it can not resolve symbol `Cast`. Do I need to use a certain namespace? Or perhaps Im using an old version of .net? Do you know how I can check?

Comment: You need `System.Linq`

Comment: Now it says "Cannot choose method from method group. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Comment: @Dgrin91 you are missing parentheses at the end

Comment: That sounds like you're missing a set of parentheses. If you copy/pasted my original post, the parentheses where missing and I edited them in to correct it a few seconds afterwards.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That works, but now it cant resolve `ToList()` :/. Perhaps because ArrayList doesnt actually have a toList? Maybe I just to do ToArray?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I ended up doing `.Cast<MyType>().ToArray().ToList()` That works with setting it to a list and using it in a for each

Comment: @Dgrin91: Note that, like at the end of the answer, if you simply use cast and var, you can end up with a raw, generic enumerable. Unless you need array indexing or add support, I'd leave it at that. No need to convert it to an array and list.

Answer (score 1):

We have [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in `C#` which is probably what are you looking for.

```
List<MyType> arr = new List<MyType>();
```

`ArrayList` is not a generic collection and it's not strongly-typed.If you are sure that your `getArrayList()` returns a collection that contains only items of type `MyType` or some type that can be convertible to `MyType`, you can use [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, otherwise use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to prevent `InvalidCastException`:

```
List<MyType> arr = getArrayList().OfType<MyType>().ToList();
```

Comment: Lists are great and all, but this doesnt tell me how to cast.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
ArrayList yourList;

List<MyType> list = yourList.Cast<MyType>().ToList();
```

If your ArrayList has any entries that are not MyType's, then you'll get an InvalidCastException.

You'll have to include the System.Linq namespace.